# EnableViewStateMac Documentation Warning?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, state

There is a warning in the @Page directive regarding the EnableViewStateMac setting found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx) that states:

"**Security Note** This attribute should never be set to false in a production Web site."

This warning seems unconditional, regardless of the Page ViewState setting (true or false).  Does this warning apply to @Pages that have EnableViewState set to false?  If the warning **does** apply in this case, why, when ViewState is turned completely off for the page and its child controls, is this a concern?

**Upgate:** The warning seems to apply, being that some doofus could drop a control that uses Control State on to a page that has ViewState = false AND ViewStateMac = false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's no viewstate there's no harm in leaving it on ... and, remember, there are cases where, despite your best attempts viewstate may sneak in, under the guise of control state, so the warning still applies.

Comment: That was my next question - because Control State still uses StateBag.  Could be me, but this seems absolutely bizarre; some knucklehead has the ability to drop a control using Control State on a page that has ViewState = false and ViewStateMac = false. There should be a way to absolutely disable ViewState on a page completely, sealing it.  Oh well.